# How to block a cross domain script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, cors

The `action` in a controller of `domain1`:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render js: 'alert("Foo")' }
  end
end
```

When I call get this `js` format in my `domain2` view, the alert works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain1/action.js"></script>
```

However, I was expecting it to not work since the `js script` is provided by the `domain1`.

I believe it is a Cross-Domain request. I am wrong?

How can I block it in Rails (using cors - I´m not considering authentication)?

request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:language=en; JSESSIONID=548BBE8340E2BCF88CC79FD406D87201; _session_id=36e9c1d96dd60d139edc669e4eb5311a
Host:domain1
If-None-Match:"4160518da6c411ed4f844684e3bd82e8"
Referer:https://domain2/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
```

response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Length:13
Content-Security-Policy:default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; font-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; media-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 02 Jul 2015 14:36:17 GMT
Etag:"68a0bef3fb4d7408f31dfd3d2958cb4d"
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-11-22)
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=631138519
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:136ef12c007055e756e4ac1b7de83046
X-Runtime:0.264848
X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge
X-Xss-Protection:1
```

Comment: You can check for the Referer header field, then block it if not domain1

Comment: yep, I could do that... but I´m more interested in understanding why it is not blocked automatically.

Comment: content scripts are not restricted by cross domain policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include code from any domain, this is how libraries like google maps work.

What you *can't* do in JavaScript is make (XMLHTTP)requests to other domains unless those domains have an origin policy that allows your domain.

Including is a script is not considered a cross domain request (this is also how [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) gets around the origin restrictions). Outputting a CORS policy is not going to stop the request.

As to how you can block the request. It depends on your situation. If you're offering the scripts as part of an API suite your best bet is to use authentication tokens.

Comment: So, if the script does a post back to my domain1, it would be considered a cross domain request?

Comment: That depends how the POST request is made. If it's made using `XMLHTTPRequest` then yes. If it's made using a `<form>` then no.